# YA book about house like a maze (like Howl's Moving Castle)

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I honestly don't remember much more but it seems really similar to the book Howl's Moving Castle - but I don't think it is.

I think our protagonist is a girl, it's her uncle's (?) house, and there are many doors inside that leads somewhere one day and somewhere else another day.
I seem to remember her finding herself in a garden one day, and she's lost, there's something about a wasp also?

I would have read it when I was about 9 (10 yrs ago), I don't remember if it was recently published at the time.

Comment: I bet it's House of Many Ways, or whatever it is called. Same author.

Comment: As Adamant says, House of Many Ways is about a girl having to look after her uncle's house, and it does have doors that lead to different places on different days. However it doesn't have any wasps in it and the only garden mentioned is her uncle's front garden, which she doesn't get lost in.

Comment: There's one like this with a boy in his father's house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diana Wynne Jones wrote a couple of follow-ups to Howl's Moving Castle, [Castle in the Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Air_(novel)) and [House of Many Ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Many_Ways). The latter sounds very like the book you describe.

[image: House of Many Ways]

The introduction on Wikipedia says:

> Charmain Baker has led a respectable, and relaxing sheltered life. She has spent her days with her nose in a book, never learning how to do even the smallest household chores. When she suddenly ends up looking after the tiny cottage of her ill Great-Uncle William she seems happy for the adventure, but the easy task of house-sitting is complicated by the fact that Great-Uncle William is also the Royal Wizard Norland and his magical house bends space and time.

Uncle William's house does have a large front garden (the gardener is a kobold!) and various adventures happen in the garden but I don't recall Charmain getting lost in. I also can't remember anything about a wasp.